# how to find the solutions of this equation (with Lambert Function)?

Tags: analysis

I need the solutions $x$, such that $x\ln|x|+\frac{1}{4}=0 $ is true. Wolframalpha gives http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xln|x|%2B1%2F4%3D0, but I never heard of the Lambert W-Function before. Can you give me a hint how to find the solutions of this equation? Best.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: After I saw this solutions I read this article about the Lambert W-Function on Wikipedia but nevertheless I have no idea to determine the solutions.

Comment: It is just a special function Lambert and Euler worked. It has a lot of applications. If you need more info, just post.

Comment: Your problem is a special case $b=e, \; a=-1/4$ of the Wiki example
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_4. Or do you want do no how you actually compute a function value?

Comment: Thank you. I want to know how to derivate (I'm not sure if that is the suitable english word, I use  http://www.dict.cc ) the solutions, how to start a possible computation to get this solutions without knowing explicitly the Lambert W-Function (sorry for my english :( )

Comment: A very simple hint: Take a starting value $x_0 = 0.5$ and iterate $x_{n+1} = -0.25 / \ln x_n$. This process approaches one solution $x = 0.11610128\dots$

Comment: ok thank you. I will try to do it. Now I know that it is not solvable with a simple analysis 1,2-calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The Lambert-W function is the solution to the inverse of $f(x)=xe^x$, where $W(xe^x)=f^{-1}(xe^x)=x$. This is also true for $W(xlnx)$. So let's get your equation into that form:
$$
xln|x|+\frac{1}{4} = 0
$$
$$
xln|x| = -\frac{1}{4}
$$
Now, in order to take the $W$ of both sides, we need to resolve this absolute value by splitting our equation into two parts, one with $ln(x)$ and one with $ln(-x)$. Here's the positive branch:
$$
W(xlnx) = W(-\frac{1}{4})
$$
$$
lnx = W(-\frac{1}{4})
$$
$$
x = e^{W(-\frac{1}{4})}
$$
This branch gives us two of our answers, $e^{W_0(-1/4)} \approx .699491$ and $e^{W_{-1}(-1/4)} \approx .116101$. Then, our negative counterpart is as follows:
$$
xln(-x) = -\frac{1}{4}
$$
$$
-xln(-x) = \frac{1}{4}
$$
$$
W\biggl(-xln(-x)\biggr) = W\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)
$$
$$
ln(-x) = W\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)
$$
$$
-x = e^{W\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}
$$
$$
x = -e^{W\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}
$$
Thus, our final value for $x$ is $-e^{W_0\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)} \approx -1.226161$. There exist, in fact, 3 more solutions in total from the $W_{-1}$ and $W_1$ branches for both $lnx$ and $ln(-x)$, however those solutions are complex answers, not real.